# Internal error: A procedure imported by 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll' could not be loaded

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

When I tried to execute sample U-SQL script on my local machine, i am getting below error.

> Error 1 E_CSC_SYSTEM_INTERNAL: Internal error! Could not load file or assembly 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I m trying to execute the script locally on Visual studio 2015

[image]]

Comment: Are you using it through Visual Studio? Or trying to submit it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following Windows patch installed ?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

In specific, you will need this one (Win7 64bits): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cdd5866a-43b3-409e-8fd7-e37b0a9ccc63